# Compile and link two files using cmake?

Tags: c, cmake, linker-scripts

I have two files in my project.
One is a ".c" file, one is a ".asm" file. First, I compile both the files into two ".o" object files and then link together using a custom linker script.
Currently, I am using a simple bash script with manual commands to build the project, but as the project size is expected to increase, I was thinking of moving the project to using cmake as its primary build system.

I have searched documentation of cmake and googled for a lot of time, although I have shortlisted some of the variables in cmake which might prove to be useful in this case, I am unable to find any sample explaining how to achieve this.

Can anybody provide me with a brief sample code on how should I go about achieving this ?

Comment: So you're asking how to compile an assembly file in cmake?

Comment: I had two problems, one is compiling assembly but I think I figured it out, so the main problem is the linking part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for an example?  Here's one from the [cmake wiki](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Assembler)

```
set(mySrcs foo.c bar.c)

set(can_use_assembler FALSE)

# test wether it is a x86 machine and as/gas is available
if("${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}" MATCHES "i.86")
   enable_language(ASM-ATT)
   if(CMAKE_ASM-ATT_COMPILER_WORKS)
      set(can_use_assembler TRUE)
      set(mySrcs ${mySrcs} codec_i86.s)
   endif(CMAKE_ASM-ATT_COMPILER_WORKS)
endif("${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}" MATCHES "i.86")

# no assembler found
if(not can_use_assembler)
   set(mySrcs ${mySrcs} codec_generic.c)
endif(not can_use_assembler)

add_executable(player ${mySrcs})
```

Because of the way that CMake works, assembling and linking are grouped together in the same step (from the programmer's perspective at least).  So `add_executable` automatically handles everything for you.

If you want to include a linker script, that gets more difficult with CMake.  The best place to look into it is [over here](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-May/037206.html).  Since the examples and instructions are too long to copy out in the SO answer box, I'll leave the reading to you.

Comment: This doesn't answer the linking part, also I told in the comments already that I have handled the assembly compilation part.

Comment: Thanks,but how should I specify my custom linker script.

Comment: @ps06756 See My edit on how to add a linker script.  It's quite annoying and is definitely something that kitware should solve in the near future.